# Why do I see generators for frameworks I have removed from a Rails 3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I comment out the lines that require the Active Record and Test Unit railties in `config/application.rb` and do a `rails generate` in the project root folder, I still see tasks for the above frameworks in the list of generators.

```
% rails generate

...
ActiveRecord:
  active_record:migration
  active_record:model
...
```

Is this expected behavior? If not, what do I do to remove these from the list of available generators?

It doesn't make or break anything, but it's annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the gems still in your Gemfile? That's the likely candidate.

Comment: Well, I have rails. Should I load the individual libraries instead?

Comment: That was a toxic question. Just tried it out, and yes, awesome: I got rid of the Active Record generators this way. Test Unit generators are still there, but that seems to be something that requires a fix on the Rails end of things. https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/5111